# UITapGestureRecognizer Will Only Register >1 taps

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

In my `viewDidLoad` func, I have followed the steps to implement a UITapGestureRecognizer, but it will not register a "single tap", only 2 or 3:

```
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapAction))
gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 3
myView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

I have tried applying it to different views higher up the hierarchy, but the same exact problem remains.  When it is set to 3 taps required, I have to tap exactly 3 times for it to work (so, I've ruled out the that initial tap is taken by another view).

Any ideas why I can't get it to register just a single tap?

Thank You!

Comment: Do you have any other `UITapGestureRecognizer`s attached to that view or any parents? How many taps are they set up for?

Comment: @AlecGorge No, I do not.  Just the one.  I have set it up for 2 and 3 taps, which both work.  When I set it to = 1, it does not register for some reason... despite which view I've applied it to..

Comment: if you remove the whole line where you set `numberOfTapsRequired`, does it work? I can't imagine it makes a difference since the default is 1, but whenever I look for a single tap I don't set anything. Just to rule that out

Comment: @AlecGorge If I remove the line, it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... So the solution to my problem was simple.  I just had to add a transparent view on the top layer of the area I was trying to collect "tap" data from.  I read that this required a "superview" to collect coordinate data from an area with multiple button objects, and I assumed that meant a view that held all the buttons, but this was incorrect.  The superview needs to be "in front of" all the objects I want to collect coordinate data from, and now a single tap works!